# How to apply the Magento 2 patches?

Tags: magento2, security, patches

I'm using the Magento 2.1.6 and I want to apply the patch `CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch`.

**How can I apply the *.patch files?**

Comment: can you please help me on how to find the required patches to install for a given Magento version. Is there any tool you are using to find them? or we should visit magento.com for patches information?

Comment: i was searching for best practice to apply these patches on a Magento 2 Composer installation. In this Artikel i posted how we Patch Magento Source. https://medium.com/@LarsRoettig/how-to-apply-patches-on-magento-2-b4fd83537f61

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Traditional**

> On **Magento Cloud** you just need to add the patch inside your m2-hotfixes folder.

You can use the traditional method:

```
git apply MAGEPatch-20181106.patch
```

or

```
patch -p1 < MDVA-14172_EE_2.2.6_COMPOSER_v1.patch
```

**Composer**

Or to solve the same situation with files being patched in the vendor directory, there is a good article on it here: http://jamescowie.me/blog/2016/12/Composer-Magento-Patches/

We did something similar in our composer file:

```
...
   "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-cache-invalidate": {
                "GH 8815: Varnish purge requests can overrun size limit": "patches/composer/github-issue-8815.patch"
            },
        }
    }
...
```

In our Magento root, we have a patches/composer directory which is where we reference them and in the extras/patches section, we tell it which Magento module to patch.

Ironically I found this post when looking at how this was done only to find our solution was already in place by our initial vendor.

Answer (score 5):

If you have git installed on your environment just use the following copy the patch on you magento root folder.

Then use:

```
$ git apply MAGETWO-67805-2017-05-17-03-04-03.patch
```

Comment: what if one doesn't keep vendor folder as part of the git repository? Doesn't this just patch core files directly?

Comment: @dchayka you need to include patch in composer.json

Comment: Thank you @GigaTodadze , I've been taking that approach.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is doing this via Composer there is a [free module](https://packagist.org/packages/zero1limited/magento2-patches) you can install it allows you to install patches from the cli.

```
magento@ce87c6cc1cdf /home/magento/htdocs/$ php bin/magento patch:list
Magento Version: 2.3.0
PRODSECBUG-2198 - This patch provides protection against the SQL injection vulnerability described under PRODSECBUG-2198
More info can be found here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/#download2288

magento@ce87c6cc1cdf /home/magento/htdocs/$ php bin/magento patch:add --patch=PRODSECBUG-2198
Patch: PRODSECBUG-2198
Message: PRODSECBUG-2198 - Added via Zero1_Patches
Magento Version: 2.3.0
SUCCESS!
The patch has been added to you composer.json
You can now run: "composer install" to apply the patch.
magento@ce87c6cc1cdf /home/magento/htdocs/$
```

I use it on [Mdoq](https://www.mdoq.io/), but it can be used anywhere.
There is a good blog post on it [here](https://www.zero1.co.uk/2019/04/12/patching-your-magento-2-store/)

Comment: I tried to email the company about adding patches but their email is broken (support@mdoq.io). It also looks like they have not added new patches for about a year. This seems to be a dead project.

Comment: @njm5785 not a dead project, apologies we missed your email. How can I help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that your Magento store is in `developer mode`

   `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
2. Download the security patch

   `git apply MAGETWO-67805-2017-05-17-03-04-03.patch`
3. After that just run below command to apply the patch

   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Have you any idea, how to remove last apply the patch?

Answer (score 0):

- **Download** the **patch file** and place it into the **root directory** of **Magento**
- Set the **developer mode** by using command:

  `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`
- **Apply the patch** by using command:

  `$ git apply CE-MAGETWO-93036-2018-07-02-07-06-53.patch`
- The possible **warnings and errors** you can get are:

> warning: vendor/magento/module-email/Model/FileName.php has
>   type 100755, expected 100644

The above warning means that the `permissions` of the FileName.php are `755` though the expected `permissions` are `644`.

If you apply the patch file twice you are expected to get an error message similar to:

> error: patch failed: vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php:534
>
> error: vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php: patch does not apply

Its ok to get the above error or warning.

**Your patch is still successfully applied**. Enjoy ;)