# Product admin edit issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, adminhtml, forms

I am getting below error in console, when i try to edit product in admin

```
 Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function
```

Referred below link and used that didn't solve my issue.

[Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197472/uncaught-typeerror-data-some-is-not-a-function)

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197472/uncaught-typeerror-data-some-is-not-a-function

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati, yes i have put my comments there also, its not worked for me, there it is asked to apply patch, how to apply it.

Comment: You can refer this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175598/how-to-apply-the-magento-2-patches

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati, first link worked for me. Can you please look into this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251640/setting-custom-product-attribute-value-in-magento-2